# OSMF Version: 2.0, error when unexpectedly broadcast is stopped

Tags: actionscript-3, osmf

I'm using OSMF Version: 2.0, build: 2494. While I connect to a Live stream and stream stopped unexpectedly (broadcaster turn it off) I get error:

```
Error: Error #2154: The NetStream Object is invalid.  This may be due to a failed NetConnection.

    at flash.net::NetStream/play2()

    at org.osmf.net::NetLoader/reconnectStream()

    at MethodInfo-2568()
```

Do someone encounter it or how I can catch it? I use

```
_mediaPlayer.addEventListener( MediaErrorEvent.MEDIA_ERROR, mediaErrorEventHandler);
```

for event handling but it does not get catch.

Comment: Are you using http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-player-10-action-script.html to unload the osmf?

Comment: nope, I manage to fix it long ago. I had to create my NetStream Object based and use it. Then I send it via the MediaErrorEvent to bottle up.

Comment: If you can explain a bit on how to send it via the mediator event (it does not get catched...), Thanks a lot! I have been struggling with this for a few days now.

Comment: Only way was to extend the OSMF class that this happen. I think it was in some RTMP Loader Base class... something like that. It was handing this netStream object